# How to get result of "reduce" at every step in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

In Python, if I wanted to use explicit functional-style programming to sum up a list, I could do

```
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.add, [3, -1, 2])
4
```

Mathematica, being closer to a pure functional language than Python, calls it *[Fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)* instead of *reduce*, but the outcome is the same.

```
In[1]:= Fold[Plus, {3, -1, 2}]
Out[1]= 4
```

So now, in Mathematica, if I wanted to get the result of the "fold" at every step during the iteration, I could use the function *FoldList*.

```
In[2]:= FoldList[Plus, {3, -1, 2}]
Out[2]= {3, 2, 4}
```

How do I get such a list (or preferably an iterator) in Python?  In general, does this functional operation have a name?

Comment: The subroutine is usually called `scan`, the mathematical operation is called *prefix sum*.

Comment: @gnat Rather than downvoting my post, if you're a mod, can you just move the question to the right board?  My question is fine and my answer is correct.  I always seem to pick the wrong StackExchange.

Comment: A couple of years ago, I tried moving a question from I think Stack Overflow to Server Fault by re-posting it, but the mods told me that I wasn't supposed to do that and that I should have asked them to move the question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the right function: in Python, it's called *accumulate*.

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate([3, -1, 2], operator.add))
[3, 2, 4]
```

It appears to only be available in Python 3.  But everyone has upgraded by now, right? :)

Comment: Simple `list(accumulate([3, -1, 2]))` is sufficient. `itertools.accumulate` is new in Python 3.2.

Comment: I came to this question (based on its general title) with a more general function instead of `operator.add` (say `lambda x, y: 2*x + 0.1*y`). For such functions the solutions works as well. If your question exceeded the sum, you could consider editing it and emphasising the general purpose.